# Can the issuer limit the amount an individual trustor can hold?

Tags: trustline

Is it possible for the issuer to control the maximum balance of (individual) trustors?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried by myself, but it looks like you will be able to control the maximum amount with [AUTHORIZATION REQUIRED flag](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#controlling-asset-holders). If you set this flag on the issuing account, each trustline requires your approval with [ALLOW TRUST](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/operation.html#allow-trust) operation. You can approve only those trustlines that match the specific criteria (check the `limit` parameter in your case).

It should work in theory, however, I'm not sure if a user can change the trust limit on the already authorized trustline.

Comment: Yes we tried that and it seems that the user can change the trust limit afterwards..

Comment: Pity, I can't think of any other way to implement your case.

Comment: That's a pity indeed, maybe we'll proceed then by monitoring trustlines for 'limit raising events' and freeze accounts that hit the upper limit